# Finding subsets satisfying specific constraint

Tags: python, boolean, subset, discrete-mathematics

I have a set of variables **S**, and a boolean function *f* defined on **S** as follows:

*f*(x<sub>1</sub>, x<sub>2</sub>, ... x<sub>n</sub>) = True iff *f*(x<sub>i</sub>, x<sub>j</sub>) = True ∀ 1 ≤ i ≤ *n* ∀ 1 ≤ j ≤ *n*, *n* > 1, else False.

*f*(a, b) is known and *f*(a, a) is True ∀ a, b in **S**.

I would appreciate some help in designing a fast algorithm that can return all subsets of **S** upon which *f* returns True.

As an example, let **S** = [a, b, c] and *f*(a, b) = *f*(b, c) = *f*(a, c) = True. The algorithm should then return [[a, b], [a, c], [b, c], [a, b, c]].

I have thought of four strategies to improve on brute force search:

1) The order of parameters of *f* doesn't matter.

2) Use the fact that *f*(a, a) is True and *f*(x<sub>i</sub>, x<sub>j</sub>) = *f*(x<sub>j</sub>, x<sub>i</sub>) so only i < j needs checking.

2) Use the fact that *f*(x<sub>1</sub>, x<sub>2</sub>, ... x<sub>*n*+1</sub>) = *f*(x<sub>1</sub>, x<sub>2</sub>, ... x<sub>*n*</sub>) ∧ (*f*(x<sub>i</sub>, x<sub>*n*+1</sub>) ∀ 1 ≤ i ≤ *n*) where ∀ denotes iterated conjunction.

3) note that 2) implies that if *f*(x<sub>1</sub>, x<sub>2</sub>, ... x<sub>*n*</sub>) returns False, then *f*(x<sub>1</sub>, x<sub>2</sub>, ... x<sub>*n*+Δ</sub>) also does, potentially reducing the solution space.

4) Returning False as soon as soon as *f*(x<sub>i</sub>, x<sub>j</sub>) is false for some i, j.

If you want to write some code, I would appreciate it if you could give it in python.

Many thanks.

Comment: f(x1, x2, ... xn) = f(xi, xj) for all i, j. This means that all the values f(x1, x1), f(x1, x2), ..., f(x2, x1), ... are equal, right?

Comment: The for all can be thought of as iterated conjunction; it means return f(x1, x1) and f(x1, x2) and f(x2, x1) and ... where and denotes logical and. This basically means return True iff they are all True, else False.

Comment: Then could you fix your notation to say what you mean? This is really confusing.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, have you implemented anything (in python) already? If so, can you add it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two-argument function `f(a, b)` can be seen as a symmetric, reflexive relation on S, which can be seen as an undirected graph.

Viewed that way, `f(x1, ..., xn)` is true iff `{x1, ..., xn}` forms a complete subgraph.

From there, you end up at the [clique problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem) which, unfortunately, turns out to be NP-complete. In other words, a fast algorithm is unlikely to exist.

Comment: Thank you very much Thomas; well spotted. I suppose it's back to the drawing board.